# Guidance needed regarding SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table, where I need to update the Check_Status from Completed to 'Not Completed' for Greatest Transaction_ID of Specific Prod_ID:

```
Tran_ID     Prod_ID    Check_Status
-------     --------   ------------
107893      XA         Completed
107892      XA         Completed
107891      XA         Completed
107890      XB         Completed
107889      XB         Completed
107888      YC         Completed
107887      YC         Completed
107886      YC         Completed
107885      YC         Completed
```

My results should be displayed as following i.e., product id `XA` has the greatest Trans Id as 107893, should be updated as 'Not-Completed'. Remaining things should be unchanged. Similarly for other Product Id `XB` and `XC`.

```
Tran_ID    Prod_ID     Check_Status
-------    --------    ------------
107893     XA          Not-Completed
107892     XA          Completed
107891     XA          Completed
107890     XB          Not-Completed
107889     XB          Completed
107888     YC          Not-Completed
107887     YC          Completed
107886     YC          Completed
107885     YC          Completed
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     UPDATE Transactions set 
    Check_Status= 'Not completed' 
     where Tran_ID IN (
        Select MAX(Tran_ID) as Tran_ID from 
Transactions Group by Prod_ID)
```

Comment: I dont know about that, I have Marked now!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use CTE for this:

```
;with cte as
(
  select tran_id, prod_id,
    row_number() over(partition by prod_id order by tran_id desc) rn,
    check_status
  from yourtable
) 
update  cte
set check_status = 'Not-Completed'
where rn = 1
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecbb6/11)

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right, fixed...the coffee hasn't kicked in yet.  Thanks :|

Comment: Thanks so much! Just looking for row_Number function, but not sure where i can apply it!! Really helpful and works like a charm!!

Comment: @Cyborgz `row_number()` comes in very handy.  If any answer is helpful, then be sure to mark it as accepted via the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @bluefeet. Thanks! I really dont know about it, Just a newbie here...Yes,Marked the Checkmark !!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE tablename t1 
SET t1.Check_Status = 'Not-Completed'
WHERE t1.TranId IN 
    (
       SELECT Max(Tran_ID) 
       FROM Tablename t2 
       GROUP BY Prod_ID
    )
```

Comment: Why where clause in inner query

Comment: @Tassadaque, Sorry I was going to write it as `join` so I messed it up